# gmapping params width/height/resolution

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Distro Kinetic
SO Ubuntu 16.04

Hello, i am trying to create a tool for mapping for Windows/Android but i first need to unsderstand how mapping works. i have a launch file to start gmapping, i am setting the xmin xmax ymin ymax values to: -10, 10, -10, 10 so at the start, the map size if im correct it should be 20 m width and 20 m height. When using rviz to check if the map size is correct, i am chcecking the corners of the map and they are showing the expected value. i am also setting the delta resolution to 0.1 so basically 10 cells it is 1 meter, so the map should be 200 cells width x 200 width cells height, but when using rostopic echo /map i see that the map being display has a width of 192 and a height of 192, i am completly lost and i have no idea why the size of the map being displayed is 192

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353261/gmapping-params-width/height/resolution/) by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the answer was way simplier than i firstly thought. The maps get created using grids thats why there cant be maps of 200 cells for example

---

Originally posted by [nalistic](https://answers.ros.org/users/55256/nalistic/) with karma: 15 on 2020-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56593/chan/) on 2021-04-25**:
Can you please elaborate? I don't understand.